# How do you make buttons for every line in a TEXT file?

Tags: java, swing, file, button

I'm trying to make buttons for every line of text in a text file. How would I add this method to my JFrame? Here is what I tried, any help would be appreciated.

```
public void makeButton()
{
    //extract name from file and add to JFrame
    try
    {
        String fileName = "C:\\Buttons\\aaa.TEXT";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            JButton b = new JButton(line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e20)
    {
        e20.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like `ArrayList<JButton>`?

Comment: Why would I need an arraylist of buttons? I'm just going through my TEXT file, and naming a button for every line in that file.

Comment: What do you want to do? Just name the buttons? Do so.

Comment: My TEXT file has a name in each line, I want to go through each line and make a button for every line having that name.

Comment: You have already have code to create button objects that compiles. What is your problem?

Comment: I guess my real question is, how would I add this method to my JFrame?

Comment: Your "real question" shouldn't be down here buried in comments -- you should edit your original question and clarify it, and you should strive to create and post a decent [mcve] as per the [help] section on asking questions.

Comment: Can I add this method to my JFrame?

Comment: Why are you asking this rather than trying? Try first -- as has been suggested to you in your way too many questions on this site -- you're doing too much asking here and too little experimenting I think, and that may be hampering your learning process. Experiment, play, try it out first always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already doing what you stated -- making a new JButton for each line of the file, but you're not doing anything with the buttons after creation. For them to be at all useful, you must add them to the GUI -- some container that is somehow displayed in your top level window (JFrame often). So add them to a  JPanel, add ActionListeners to them as well, and you're all set.

Comment: So, it's correct? I just have to do something like, frame.add(b)?

Comment: @D.Maximov: I wouldn't add them directly to the JFrame, again I'd add them to a JPanel (using a decent layout -- perhaps a GridLayout?) and add **that** to the JFrame. But you should be experimenting more with your code.